# Get Frame rate statistics on android

Tags: android, graphics, opengl-es, surfaceflinger

I am doing a project where I am scaling the frequency of the GPU of a Nexus 7 through the kernel to save power.
To measure QoS/performance I am trying to collect data on frames rendered (drawn/dropped). I am hoping to run a few games/videos to see the frame rate. I am aware that I can collect data through the adb with the command

```
$>adb shell dumpsys gfxinfo <package_name>
```

in developer mode with "Profile GPU rendering" enabled. This only outputs the time taken to draw/process/execute for the last 128 frames for each package/application. I am wondering if there is a hack to increase the number of frames

or

if I can get rendered frame statistics another way. I understand we can use systrace/tracer for OpenGL ES. Neither outputs stats-just wave forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is the newer Nexus 7 with the snapdragon chip you could consider using the [Adreno Profiler](https://developer.qualcomm.com/mobile-development/maximize-hardware/mobile-gaming-graphics-adreno/tools-and-resources) from their site. You'll have to make an account first though.

Comment: I used the Adreno profiler. It doesn't output raw time taken for a frame to be rendered. Instead it outputs FPS. I am also not sure how many frames it averages FPS measurement with. Do you know how many?

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a top result on Google for "frame rate statistics on android" I'm going to offer another suggestion. `dumpsys gfxinfo` clears that buffer each time you access it, so you if you poll it you can collect data as long as you like.

Comment: Here's a python script I wrote to do just that, then make a graph of it: https://github.com/Turnsole/cookie-butter

Answer (score 1):

You could use [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gamebench.metricscollector) app. It measures FPS of any game in the play store. It also records screenshots so you can understand what was happening when the FPS Drops.

Comment: When promoting your own product, always disclose your affiliation. http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior

Comment: I am one of the developers of the app :) Thanks for pointing this out